# Extracting data from web page to CSV file, only last row saved

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm faced with the following challenge: I want to get all financial data about companies and I wrote a code that does it and let's say that the result is like below:

```
Unnamed: 0    I Q 2017   II Q 2017  \
0     Przychody netto ze sprzedaży (tys. zł)         137         134   
1   Zysk (strata) z działal. oper. (tys. zł)        -423        -358   
2             Zysk (strata) brutto (tys. zł)        -501        -280   
3             Zysk (strata) netto (tys. zł)*        -399        -263   
4                      Amortyzacja (tys. zł)         134         110   
5                           EBITDA (tys. zł)        -289        -248   
6                           Aktywa (tys. zł)      27 845      26 530   
7                  Kapitał własny (tys. zł)*      22 852      22 589   
8                   Liczba akcji (tys. szt.)  13 921,975  13 921,975   
9                         Zysk na akcję (zł)       -0029       -0019   
10            Wartość księgowa na akcję (zł)        1641        1623   
11             Raport zbadany przez audytora           N           N
```

but 464 times more.

Unfortunately when I want to save all 464 results in one CSV file I can save only one last result. Not all 464 results, just one... Could you help me save all? Below is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd    

url = 'https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'lxml')
# Find the second table on the page
t = soup.find_all('table')[0]


#Read the table into a Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_html(str(t))[0]

#get 
names_of_company = df["Walor AD"].values

links_to_financial_date = []
#all linkt with the names of companies
links = []

for i in range(len(names_of_company)):
    new_string = 'https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje/' + names_of_company[i] + '/wyniki-finansowe'
    links.append(new_string)

############################################################################

for i in links:
    url2 = f'https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje/{names_of_company[0]}/wyniki-finansowe'

    page2 = requests.get(url2)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page2.content,'lxml')
# Find the second table on the page
    t2 = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    df2 = pd.read_html(str(t2))[0]

    df2.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it.  You're just overwriting your CSV each time.  Replace

```
df2.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None)
```

with

```
with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
    df2.to_csv(f, header=False)
```

in order to append  to the CSV instead of overwriting it.

Also, your example doesn't work because this:

```
for i in links:
    url2 = f'https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje/{names_of_company[0]}/wyniki-finansowe'
```

should be:

```
for i in links:
    url2 = i
```

When the website has no data, skip and move on to the next one:

```
    try:
        t2 = soup.find_all('table')[0]
        df2 = pd.read_html(str(t2))[0]

        with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
            df2.to_csv(f, header=False)
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! but when I did what you said there is a issue with below
`t2 = soup.find_all('table')[0]` 
there is error: IndexError: list index out of range. Could you know why perhaps ?

Comment: That seems to happen on this https://www.bankier.pl/gielda/notowania/akcje/SELVITA-PDA/wyniki-finansowe because this symbol has no data on the website.  I say just skip it with a try: except: